# Uncompilable source code - not a statement at arrays.main(arrays.java:4) Java Result: 1

Tags: java

I basically just started yestarday learning java. I can't understand what this error is, the code is very simple

```
class arrays {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

         int[] = numbers;
        numbers = new int [5];

        numbers [0] = 35;
        numbers [1] = 65;
        numbers [2] = 135;
        numbers [3] = 335;
        numbers [4] = 535;


        System.out.print (numbers[1] );
    }
}
```

the error is the one on the title

any suggestions? i am using Netbean

Comment: What exactly do you think `int[] = numbers`; will do? When the compiler is complaining about something, always try to think carefully about exactly what you're trying to achieve with that line, and then check it *really* carefully - e.g. against a book if necessary.

Comment: [How to declare arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
int[] = numbers;
```

to

```
int[] numbers;
```

or maybe even better, change

```
int[] = numbers;
numbers = new int [5];
```

to

```
int[] numbers = new int [5];
```

Per Jon Skeet:

> What exactly do you think `int[] = numbers;` will do? When the compiler is complaining about something, always try to think carefully about exactly what you're trying to achieve with that line, and then check it *really* carefully - e.g. against a book if necessary.

Comment: This answer is a community wiki, so anyone who wants to, please feel free to improve it.

Comment: Thanks you. I am actualy following a tutorial online. He made the mistake and corrected it later without showing it. that's why i was confused. not it works.

Comment: @AlexMercuri: not to worry. None of us were born with Java knowledge, and the first steps are always the hardest, but please don't give up. Keep on plugging and it **will** get easier, trust me!

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- You initialize a non-existent array. You need to specify the name of the array you want to create
- You did not structure your code to make it easy-to-read
- Class names are usually written in camel-case, starting with a big letter

Suggestion:

```
class Arrays {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int[] numbers = new int [5]; //correct specification for your array

        numbers [0] = 35;
        numbers [1] = 65;
        numbers [2] = 135;
        numbers [3] = 335;
        numbers [4] = 535;


        System.out.print (numbers[1]);
    }
}
```